# Why can't I create a .NET Core/Standard 2.0 project?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I've installed the .NET Core 2.0 SDK from https://www.microsoft.com/net/core. If I run `dotnet new classlib --framework netstandard2.0` I get the following output:

```
Error: Invalid values for parameter(s) [--framework] for template Class library.

Options:
  -f|--framework
                  netcoreapp1.0     - Target netcoreapp1.0
                  netcoreapp1.1     - Target netcoreapp1.1
                  netstandard1.0    - Target netstandard1.0
                  netstandard1.1    - Target netstandard1.1
                  netstandard1.2    - Target netstandard1.2
                  netstandard1.3    - Target netstandard1.3
                  netstandard1.4    - Target netstandard1.4
                  netstandard1.5    - Target netstandard1.5
                  netstandard1.6    - Target netstandard1.6
              Configured Value: netstandard2.0
              Default: netstandard1.4
```

If I omit the `--framework` parameter it creates a .NET Standard 1.4 app; I can then change the target framework manually to `netstandard2.0` and build it with no problems.

In Visual Studio 2017.4 the project properties page displays blank against the target framework.

Running `dotnet --info` produces the following:

```
.NET Command Line Tools (1.0.4)

Product Information:
 Version:            1.0.4
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  af1e6684fd

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.15063
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 2.0.0
  Build    : e8b8861ac7faf042c87a5c2f9f2d04c98b69f28d
```

Does this mean I need to update my CLI tools, and if so how? I thought they were included in the SDK. And how do I get Visual Studio to understand about 2.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Worked this out in the end: I had an old `global.json` file in my root code directory that referenced version `1.0.0-rc1-final`. Deleting this enabled the 2.0 tooling.

Comment: Yes. The global.json file is used, among other things, to globally configure the version of dotnet to use. If you don't need to target a specific version, you can remove it, or just simply update the version in that file to the new one you're now targeting.

Comment: i was having a problem where a project using .net standard 2.0 compiled fine in it's own solution, but would not work when added to an existing solution. .net standard 2.0 was missing from the target framework area in visual studio with no explanation. this was the answer.